# Как подсчитать количество проверенных url?

Tags: python, requests

Есть файл с url с примерным содержимым

```
https://www.docker.com/products/docker-hub
https://www.codewars.com/
https://realpython.com/
https://githubX.com/
www.digitalocean.com
https://www.linux.org.ru/
```

Цель подсчитать количество доступyых/адресов. Но подсчет получается не верным, в случае когда все адреса верны, получаю результат 1

```
import requests

with open('urls.txt', 'r') as file:
    urls = file.read().splitlines()

for url in urls:
    good_urls = 0
    bad_url = 0
    r = requests.get(url)
    sc = r.status_code
    if sc == 200:
        valid = 'Valid'
        good_urls =+ 1
    else:
        valid = "Not valid"
        bad_url =+ 1
    print(good_urls)
    print(bad_url)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
good_urls =+ 1
```

теперь `good_urls` равен `+1`, а плюс один это просто `1`

Чтобы увеличить числа на один надо писать

```
good_urls += 1
```

---

Место

```
file.read().splitlines()
```

лучше писать

```
file.readlines()
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!